# Issue with expandablelistview indicator

Tags: android, json, listview, android-studio, onclicklistener

I am creating multilevel expandable list view with list view. So I want indicator of the list view changed when clicking it.I have two png images in drawable folder.The click event not working properly.When clicking the minus sign is not coming.I am referring **[this](http://twocentscode.blogspot.in/2014/02/three-level-expandable-listview.html)**.
my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<NLevelItem> lists;
    ListView listView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue1, requestQueue2;
    int[] firstcatid = null,secondcatid = null;
    String firsttitle[] = null,secondtitle[] = null;
    int j = 0;
    //ArrayList<Group> list,list2,list3;
    NLevelItem parent;
    Boolean b=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lists = new ArrayList<NLevelItem>();
       // Random rng = new Random();
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        requestQueue1= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://www.fasr.com/cntrldata/ezproductfristcategory.php",
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            //list = new ArrayList<Group>();
                            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("hi");
                            JSONArray ja2 = response.getJSONArray("hi2");
                            JSONArray ja3 = response.getJSONArray("hi3");
                            firsttitle = new String[ja.length()];
                            firstcatid = new int[ja.length()];
                            JSONObject jsonObject2 = null, jsonObject3 = null, jsonObject;
                            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                                jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);


                                // Log.e("hie",jsonObject2.getInt("second_category_id")+"");
                                //jsonObject3 = ja3.getJSONObject(i);
                                firstcatid[i] = jsonObject.getInt("first_category_id");
                                firsttitle[i] = jsonObject.getString("first_category_name");
                            }
                            secondcatid = new int[ja2.length()];
                            for (int i = 0; i < ja2.length(); i++) {
                                jsonObject2 = ja2.getJSONObject(i);
                                secondcatid[i] = jsonObject2.getInt("second_category_id");
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                                final NLevelItem grandParent = new NLevelItem(new SomeObject(firsttitle[i]), null, new NLevelView() {

                                    @Override
                                    public View getView(NLevelItem item) {
                                        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                                        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                                        final ImageView iv=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                                        //tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                                        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
/*
                                        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                if(!b){
                                                    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_minus);
                                                    b=true;
                                                }else {
                                                    b=false;
                                                    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_add);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });*/

                                        String name = (String) ((SomeObject) item.getWrappedObject()).getName();
                                        tv.setText(name);
                                        return view;
                                    }
                                });
                                lists.add(grandParent);
                                //int numChildren = rng.nextInt(4) + 1;
                                for (int j = 0; j < ja2.length(); j++) {
                                    jsonObject2 = ja2.getJSONObject(j);

                                    if (firstcatid[i] == jsonObject2.getInt("first_category_id")) {

                                        parent = new NLevelItem(new SomeObject(jsonObject2.getString("second_category_name")), grandParent, new NLevelView() {

                                            @Override
                                            public View getView(NLevelItem item) {
                                                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                                                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                                                //tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                                                tv.setPadding(20,0,0,0);
                                                String name = (String) ((SomeObject) item.getWrappedObject()).getName();
                                                tv.setText(name);
                                                return view;
                                            }
                                        });

                                        lists.add(parent);     }                              // int grandChildren = rng.nextInt(5) + 1;
                                    for (int k = 0; k < ja3.length(); k++) {
                                        jsonObject3 = ja3.getJSONObject(k);
                                        if (secondcatid[j] == jsonObject3.getInt("second_category_id")) {
                                        NLevelItem child = new NLevelItem(new SomeObject(jsonObject3.getString("third_category_name")), parent, new NLevelView() {

                                            @Override
                                            public View getView(NLevelItem item) {
                                                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                                                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                                                //tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                                tv.setPadding(40,0,0,0);
                                                String name = (String) ((SomeObject) item.getWrappedObject()).getName();
                                                tv.setText(name);
                                                return view;
                                            }
                                        });

                                        lists.add(child);}
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            NLevelAdapter adapter = new NLevelAdapter(lists);
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                                        long arg3) {
                                    ((NLevelAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).toggle(arg2);
                                    ((NLevelAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter();

                                }
                            });
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),url[2],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //output.setText(data);
                            //ExpListItems =  list;
                            // ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ExpListItems);
                            // ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", error.toString());

                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue1.add(jsonObjectRequest);



    }

    class SomeObject {
        public String name;

        public SomeObject(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

my listitem xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/listItemContainer">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="#020202" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my pic is
[image]

Answer (score 1):

replace indicator in below condition in your adapter's `getGroupView()` method

```
if(isExpanded)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            @Override
            public View getView(NLevelItem item)
            {
                View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seperated_cows_first_row, null);

                TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tct_name);
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.select_icon);

                String name = ((ListObject) item.getWrappedObject()).getName();
                tv.setText(name);

                if (item.isExpanded())
                    icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_selector_icon_down);
                else
                    icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_selector_icon_up);

                return convertView;
            }
```

this solved my issue